# Supporting Multiple Types Of Authentication In (Only) Specific Web API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm fairly new to Web API and have an existing app that, by default, uses federated authentication.

However, I have one specific controller that I'd like to use *either* the default federated auth, or a second method that essentially uses a password sent in an HTTP header.

My initial Googling turned up stuff like this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongmeig1/archive/2012/02/27/supporting-multiple-authentication-schemes-with-web-api.aspx

...but the approach (using an HTTP module to set the HttpContext.User) seems to be universal to a site rather than targeted to a specific controller.

Plus, I'm wondering if there are more modern approaches available since the blog was written in 2012.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

EDIT: In further digging, it seems like I want to use an OverrideAuthenticationAttribute in conjunction with a custom authentication filter per:
[What OverrideAuthenticationAttribute is for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549726/what-overrideauthenticationattribute-is-for)

...but I'm trying to figure out the best way to do it (preserving default, while also adding an additional auth option).

Comment: have you been able to figure this out?

I have a similar requirement where I need to use a web API (no MVC) for both an angular client which will authenticate using a 3rd party SSO Identity Server with user/pwd, but also need the API to be accessible by some internal services such as BizTalk and thus would use a different flow like api key or token in custom http header.
Any ideas?

Comment: @ThiagoSilva - I think what we ended up doing is using an OverrideAuthentication and OverrideAuthorization attribute on the service/method, then use a custom AuthorizeAttribute that looked for everything we wanted. It probably isn't the best way, but it worked.