# Override authorization filter with another

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, authorize-attribute, asp.net-mvc-filters

I have a default `CustomAuthorizeAttribute` defined in my Web Api project.

```
config.Filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizeAttribute());
```

However I have a special Controller where I would like to use a `SpecialAuthorizeAttribute`.

```
[SpecialAuthorize]
public class MySpecialController : ApiController
```

In the Asp.Net vNext we have a new attribute to override the default filters, but how could I make it work in the Web Api 2?

**Edit 1:**

One possible (but not ideal) solution is make the CustomAuthorizeAttribute check if there's another AuthorizeAttribute in the scope of the Controller or Action. In my case I have only the SpecialAuthorizeAttribute so:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<SpecialAuthorizeAttribute>().Any() || actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<SpecialAuthorizeAttribute>().Any())
        {
            return;
        }
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    }

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnAuthorizationAsync(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return base.OnAuthorizationAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could apply your CustomAuthorizeAttribute to the other controllers as opposed to making it global by adding it to the config.  It means you need to decorate every controller, but it probably more clearly defines what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OverrideAuthenticationAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.overrideauthenticationattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).
As you can [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549726/what-overrideauthenticationattribute-is-for) this attribute is used to suppress global authentication filters.

Answer (score 0):

OverrideAuthorization attribute is the exact fit (in ASP.NET Web API 2) for your requirement. You can find its usage and purpose in simple terms in [this](https://ramanisandeep.wordpress.com/tag/overrideauthorization/) article.